# fopen in binary mode returns null to existing file

Tags: c, fopen

I have a binary file ('''simdisk.bin'''). I opened it in  'r'  mode and i've no problems to read it. Now, i want to open it in binary mode (rb+) to write and read in binary, but i get a nill pointer.

I made a test.c file to try it with this main:

```
int main(int argc, char const *argv[])
{
 fp = fopen("simdisk.bin", "rb+");
 printf("Ptr: %p\n", fp);
 fclose(fp);
}
```

Comment: Do you have permission to *write* to the file? The `+` indicates you want to update it.

Comment: You can check the value of errno

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My guess is you don't have permission to *write* to the file, which is what you're requesting with the `+` modifier, and it has nothing to do with the binary thing (the `b` modifier).

Try this, which will *tell* you the reason why it's unable to open the file - not found? no permission? etc.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <errno.h>

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
   FILE *fp = fopen("simdisk.bin", "rb+");

   if (fp == 0)
   {
       printf("Cannot open file: error=%s\n", strerror(errno));
       exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
   }
   printf("Ptr: %p\n", fp);
   fclose(fp);

   return EXIT_SUCCESS;
}
```

You can also test by changing the mode to `"rb"` - which wants read+binary but not update - and it's likely to work just fine because you're not asking to *write* to the file.

Answer (score -1):

Effectively i haven`t the permissions to write on it. I had to change the permissions: "chmod 777 simdisk.bin".

Thanks!

Comment: It's a poor idea to use `chmod 777` for anything unless that specific mask is needed, which it rarely is. You don't need to execute this file, right? Instead, add just the permissions actually required, and even then it's wise to use the symbolic notation rather than numeric. `chmod a+w simdisk.bin` says "for all (`a`) add (`+`) write (`w`) permission to file `simdisk.bin`", which gives the permission required without giving more.  If you happen to be in the same group as the file, then you only have to add  write for the group (`g+w`) and not for everybody else. `777` is a bad habit.